# Best way to generate a unique ID in java

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

What is the best way to generate a unique ID in java. People generally use

```
String id = System.currentTimeMillis+ someStaticCounter;
```

But this approach would require synchronization in multithreaded applications.

I am using

```
try 
{
   Thread.sleep(1); 
  //This sleep ensures that two consecutive calls from the same thread does not return the same id.
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
 // do nothing;
}
id = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

This approach helps me from synchronisation overheads..

Is there any better approach please suggest?

Comment: Do you need this ID to be unique across multiple VMs?

Comment: Side-comment: thread waiting 1ms don't guard against using same currentTimeMillis. If two threads start sleeping at the same ms (x), the end sleeping at the same ms (x+1), they have the same posibility of concurrency than before the sleep.

Comment: This sleep is to prevent the same thread from generating the same id.

In case of two different threads -- Thread.currentThread().getId()
would ensure the the id is different for two threads even if the currentTimeMillis() is same for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about UUID:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29

Answer (score 1):

UUID.randomUUID()